# AutoForm.getFieldValue for array fields

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a schema declared as:

```
JobSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    responsibilities: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true
    },
    'responsibilities.$': {
        min: 2,
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                class: 'form-control'
            },
            placeholder: 'E.g. "Build tools according to specifications"'
        }
    }
});
```

Also I have an UI helper declared as:

```
Template.registerHelper('currentFieldValue', function (fieldName) {
    return AutoForm.getFieldValue('insertJobForm', fieldName) || '';
});
```

I have a template where I used this helper to generate a form preview. It works like charm for all fields except the array ones. Nothing is being rendered. Any ideas?

```
{{# if currentFieldValue "responsibilities"}}
    <h3>Responsibilities</h3>
    {{{currentFieldValue "responsibilities"}}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty workaround:

**job_create.js**

```
Template.jobCreate.helpers({
    responsibilities: function() {
        var formData = AutoForm.getFormValues('insertJobForm');
        return formData.insertDoc.responsibilities || [];
    }
});
```

**job_create.html**

```
{{# if responsibilities}}
    <h3>Responsibilities</h3>
    {{responsibilities}}
{{/if}}
```